# How to trigger airflow dag with REST API (I get "Property is read-only - 'state'", error)

Tags: python-3.x, rest, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-api

I am trying to trigger airflow dags with REST API. It does not work. I get an ERROR 400 with response:

```
{
  "detail": "Property is read-only - 'state'",
  "status": 400,
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/BadRequest"
}
```

I tried it via CURL and with Python requests module and results are the same.

Example:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
auth = ('test', 'test')
import json
body = {
  "conf": {},
  "dag_run_id": "string",
  "execution_date": "2021-04-15T14:04:43.602Z",
  "state": "success"
}
req = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/dags/sleeper/dagRuns",
                   headers=headers, auth=auth, data=json.dumps(body))
```

Do I need to specify something in Airflow config or in Dag to make it possible to run it?
Because as I understand there is something with permissions ?
`"Property is read-only - 'state'",`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the `state` key from the body.

i.e.

```
body = {
  "conf": {},
  "dag_run_id": "string",
  "execution_date": "2021-04-15T14:04:43.602Z"
}
```

The [Airflow REST API docs for that endpoint](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run) says `state` is required in the body, however you shouldn't need to include that in your request. I've tested it locally (Airflow v2.0.1) without `state` in the body of the request and it appears to work!

Comment: Hi, that was a case :) But anyway when I am trying to execute script via web http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/ui/#/DAGRun/post_dag_run it's working, but localy when I try to execute it with my python code I get

```{
  "detail": null,
  "status": 403,
  "title": "Forbidden",
  "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/PermissionDenied"
}```. Do you know if I need add something in my python script to have permissions to make a request ?

Comment: It could be a security related issue with your setup. Have a read through here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/index.html - I'd suggest creating a new question on stack overflow with more information about your issue, it will get more exposure and a better chance of an answer! If you do so, leave a link to the question here as I may be able to help with more info.

Comment: did you manage to address the issue?

Comment: Adding comment this is still true as of Airflow v2.4.1 as well

Answer (score 2):

Could solve it, with:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

auth = ('test', 'test')

body = {
  "conf": {},
}

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/dags/sleeper/dagRuns",
                   headers=headers, 
                   auth=auth, 
                   data=json.dumps(body)
                 )
```

See link: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ui/#/DAGRun/post_dag_run

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this answer solves the problem. if this doesnt work out of the box, you have to take a look at the config file and change basic_auth to password_auth like this (under api section)
[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.password_auth